# Odd generic constraint issue

Tags: c#, generics

Why doesn’t this work?!

```
    public interface IBus
    {
        void Subscribe<T>(ISubscribe<T> subscriber) where T : class, IEvent;
        void Send<T>(IEvent @event) where T : class, IEvent;
    }

    class InMemoryEventBus : IBus
    {
        private readonly IDictionary<ISubscribe<IEvent>, Type> _subscribers;

        public InMemoryEventBus()
        {
            _subscribers= new Dictionary<ISubscribe<IEvent>, Type>();
        }

        public void Subscribe<T>(ISubscribe<T> subscriber) where T : class, IEvent
        {
            _subscribers.Add(subscriber, typeof(T));
        }

        public void Send<T>(IEvent @event) where T : class, IEvent
        {
            foreach (var subscriber in _subscribers.Where(subscriber => subscriber.Value == typeof(T)))
            {
                subscriber.Key.Handle(@event);
            }
        }
    }

    public interface IEvent
    {
        Guid EventId { get; set; }
    }

    public interface ISubscribe<T> where T : IEvent
    {
        void Handle(T @event);
    }

    public class StockLevelDroppedBellowMinimumLevelEvent : IEvent
    {
        public Guid EventId { get; set; }

        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
```

I get:

```
cannot convert from 'IHandle<T>' to 'IHandle<IEvent>'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: It was actually `ISubscribe` which needed to be covariant - but now that we can see the declaration of `ISubscribe`, you *can't* make it covariant - only contravariant.

In general, types aren't generically variant. For example, an `ICollection<string>` isn't an `ICollection<object>` - which is a good job, otherwise this would compile:

```
ICollection<string> strings = new List<string>();
ICollection<object> objects = strings; // Fortunately this isn't valid
objects.Add(new Button()); // This should be fine of course...
string x = strings[0]; // But what would this do?!
```

In your case, I believe you'll need to change your dictionary - you'll be able to guarantee that the "right" type of `ISubscribe` is used in each case. However, you're using the dictionary in a *very* odd way - you should reverse the key and value types, like this:

```
class InMemoryEventBus : IBus
{
    private readonly IDictionary<Type, object> _subscribers;

    public InMemoryEventBus()
    {
        _subscribers = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
    }

    public void Subscribe<T>(ISubscribe<T> subscriber) where T : IEvent
    {
        _subscribers.Add(typeof(T), subscriber);
    }

    public void Send<T>(IEvent @event) where T : class, IEvent
    {
        object value;
        if (_subscribers.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out value))
        {
             ISubscriber<T> subscriber = (ISubscriber<T>) value;
             subscriber.Handle(@event);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I added the covariant to the IEVent it goes ape-shi

any pointers?

Comment: @iwayneo: Apologies, it's `ISubscribe` which needs to be covariant - editing.

Comment: But then I get Invalid variance: The type parameter 'T' must be contravariantly valid

Comment: @iwayneo: Have a look now. You should be able to just drop my class in - having fixed the typo in your interface name (IScubscribe -> ISubscribe)

Comment: @iwayneo: Yes, your interface fundamentally can't be covariant; I couldn't have told that before seeing it. But an `ISubscribe<Foo>` *isn't* logically an `ISubscribe<IEvent>` - I can't just ask it to handle *any* `IEvent`, can I? Only the right kind of event.

Comment: Shouldn't 

_subscribers= new Dictionary<ISubscribe<IEvent>, Type>();

be

_subscribers= new Dictionary<Type, ISubscribe<IEvent>>();

in the ctor?  I'm a little afraid to edit a Skeet answer. ;)

Comment: @ChrisSimmons: Not quite - it should be `_subscribers = new Dictionary<Type, object>();` Fixed though :)